# How to understand jFileChooser1.showSaveDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I try to understand "`jFileChooser1.showSaveDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION`"   what this means?

i think `jFileChooser1.showSaveDialog(this)`  returns a `SaveDialog` but `JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION`  returns `yes` or `ok`.
How they can equals?

```
      private void save() {
    if (jFileChooser1.showSaveDialog(this) ==
      JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        save(jFileChooser1.getSelectedFile());
    }
  }

  /** Save file with specified File instance */
  private void save(File file) {
    try {
      // Write the text in jta to the specified file
      BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(
        new FileOutputStream(file));
      byte[] b = (jta.getText()).getBytes();
      out.write(b, 0, b.length);
      out.close();

      // Display the status of the save file operation in jlblStatus
      jlblStatus.setText(file.getName()  + " Saved ");
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
      jlblStatus.setText("Error saving " + file.getName());
    }
  }
```

Comment: It's actually comparing not to the dialog, but to which button you click on to close it (OK-CANCEL, for instance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the JavaDocs for this API

```
public int showSaveDialog(Component parent) throws HeadlessException
```

Pops up a "Save File" file chooser dialog. Note that the text that appears in the approve button is determined by the L&F.
Parameters:
parent - the parent component of the dialog, can be null; see showDialog for details
Returns:
the return state of the file chooser on popdown:

- JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION`
- JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION
- JFileChooser.ERROR_OPTION if an error occurs or the dialog is dismissed

The JavaDocs can be found here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#showSaveDialog(java.awt.Component)